# CURL: send a notify(POST) while upload file

Tags: c, curl

`cURL` has already performance a `POST` request to send a file.

However, the file transfer takes a long time.

And then I got a message, I need to response to host with another url.

How I can do that with `cURL`?

Note: Im using C language program.

Comment: Your question is unclear: which side needs to send a new URL in response? Is it the client (where you're executing curl) or the server (which is receiving the POST request)?

Comment: Yes. It's. The `cURL` execute in the client and server will receive the POST request.